# How to convert string into double value in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, type-conversion, double

I am building simple C# Winforms desktop app using .NET framework.
I need to convert a string like "172.5632" into double value.

I tried `Double.parse()` and `Convert.toString()`.

Both of them didn't work and I get an error

> Input string is not in correct format exception

And if I changed `.` to `,` (dot to comma), then the exception disappears, but the converted double value is not correct.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10, and using .NET 4.7.2.

It is really weird as this is very basic issue.

Comment: what does your country use as a decimal separator?

Comment: We use dot so 3.14 or 15.72

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a culture thing, make sure to specify invariant culture format

```cs
string doubleNumber = "172.5632";
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(doubleNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Output: 172.5632
```

Comment: Yeah, right. I managed to find the solution.

Comment: Yeah, right. I did double.Parse(doubleNumber, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")). It worked.  Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    string input = "172.5632";
    double result;
    if (double.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Conversion failed.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.` with `,` whichever works for you.

```
Convert.ToDouble("172.5632");
```

OR

```
double.Parse("172.5632", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```